# yii findByAttributes simple usage

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

This code gives me the whole table perfectly

```
$array_of_data= ModelName::model()->findAll();
```

Now I'm trying to get all data of table where column name 'sex' equals to male.
This code is not working. why?

```
$array_of_data= ModelName::model()->findByAttributes(array('sex'=>'male'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong function :)

It's `findAllByAttributes()` you need.

Answer (score 0):

you Can use Followin

```
Company::model()->findAll(array(
   'condition' => 'sex= :sex',
   'params' => array(
       ':sex' => 'male'
   )
));
```

[http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/18152-findallbyattributes/page_*p*_89436_*hl*_findallbyattribute+#entry89436](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/18152-findallbyattributes/page__p__89436__hl__findallbyattribute+#entry89436)